# I applied debugshowcheckedmodebanner: false, but still debug tag show on each screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have multiple screens. all the screens are showing debug tag. I am implementing `debugshowcheckedmodebanner: false`, into material app of my main file but debug tag shows on right top of each of the screen. I am not sure where I am making mistake.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:async';a
import 'home.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: splash(),
  ));
}

class splash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _splashState createState() => _splashState();
}

class _splashState extends State<splash> {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(
      Duration(seconds: 3),
          () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp(),
      ),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
      return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Do you want to exit?"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, false);
                  },
                  child: Text("No")),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, true);
                  },
                  child: Text("yes"))
            ],
          ));
    }

    Orientatoin();
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              child: Image.asset('imges/splash.png'),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
    );
  }
}

void Orientatoin() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are not toggling the banner from dev tools or in the flutter inspector panel on the right hand side of the screen in android studio/Intellij.

In the code you have, their is an extra `a` in line 3. check that your code compiles, and not running an older version of your code base.

Comment: how can I check it from flutter inspector please? 
that 'a' mistakenly type while putting the question.

Comment: in android studio/Intellij top menu bar: View -> Tool Windows -> Flutter Inspector.in the inspector you can find "Hide debug mode banner" under "more Actions" dropdown.

Comment: Aligator I had another materialApp widget on other screen so I removed that materialApp (as whole application should have one materialApp widget) and now everything is perfect. many thanks for your response stay blessed

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you have just a single `MaterialApp widget` in your project and all screens in your application must be a child of this widget.

Answer (score 0):

You must insert "debugshowcheckedmodebanner: false" in main.dart and all screen files then Ok

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issues, and for me it was happening because I was doing a hot-reload / hot-restart. I restarted the App (Stop main.dart, then Run main.dart again) and issue got resolved. It seem hot-restart doesn't 'rebuild' the MaterialApp.

Answer (score -1):

0

I faced this issues, and for me it was happening because I was doing a hot-reload / hot-restart. I restarted the App (Stop main.dart, then Run main.dart again) and issue got resolved. It seem hot-restart doesn't 'rebuild' the MaterialApp.

Comment: Copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/77265658/2227743. Please delete.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).